# Cleaning tweets and Storing daily tweets in database

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, sentiment-analysis, data-cleaning

I am trying to determine ratings of TV Series regarding tweets. Therefore i have a Twitter data consist of tweets, mentions, hashtags in ArrayLists seperately via using Java with Twitter4J library. 
My purpose is to first clean tweets and then analyze them by using Natural Language Processing. 
In cleaning phase, there are duplicate tweets exist like retweets from different users as well as more than one tweets from one user, which should be cleaned.
In analyzing phase, i will use one NLP library to parse the roots to be able to determine ratings. So far i've written this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new TwitterApplication().retrieve();

}

public void retrieve(){
    logger.info("Retrieving tweets...");
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
    Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();

    ArrayList<String> tweetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> hashtagList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> mentionList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Query query = new Query("The Walking Dead");

    Date date=new Date();
    String modifiedDate= new SimpleDateFormat("2015-11-25").format(date);
    String modifiedDate2= new SimpleDateFormat("2015-11-26" ).format(date);
    query.setSince(modifiedDate);
    query.setUntil(modifiedDate2);


    query.lang("en");
    query.setCount(100);

    System.out.println("key:" + twitter.getConfiguration().getOAuthConsumerKey());
    System.out.println("secret: " + twitter.getConfiguration().getOAuthConsumerSecret());
    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken("**************", "***********");

    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

    try {

    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

    System.out.println("Count : " + result.getTweets().size()) ;        

    for (Status tweet : result.getTweets()) {           

    for(HashtagEntity hashtag : tweet.getHashtagEntities()){
        //System.out.println(hashtag);
        hashtagList.add(hashtag.getText().toString());
    }

    for(UserMentionEntity mention : tweet.getUserMentionEntities()){
        mentionList.add(mention.getScreenName().toString());
    }



    //try to fetch only one of the retweets, but it doesn't work        
    /*  
    int once=0;
    if(tweet.isRetweeted() && once==0)
    {
    tweetList.add(tweet.getText());
    once++;
    } 
    */

    tweetList.add(tweet.getText());


    }

    } catch (TwitterException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Failed to search tweets" + e.getMessage());

    }

    System.out.println("Tweets:");
    for(String t :tweetList){
        System.out.println(t);
    }

    System.out.println("Hashtags:");
    for(String h:hashtagList){
        System.out.println( h);
    } 

    System.out.println("Mentions:");
    for(String m:mentionList){
        System.out.println(m);
    } 



    logger.info("done! ");

}
```

As you've seen i used ArrayLists to store them temporarily. What i want to ask is, after cleaning phase should i store them in database like MySQL, MongoDB etc. ? if i should, how can i store them effectively? Considering i will analyze(obtain the roots and give them points according to sentiment analysis) tweets later.

Answer (score 1):

The question of storing or not mainly depends on what you plan to do with the data afterwards. Normally because using NLP on tweets (tokenization, stopword removal, stemming, etc.) can take some time, it might be wise to store the processed data. However if you only need the data once and calculate some metrics on it, you might not need to store it at all.

If you want to process queries on the processed data in the future, like "give me all processed tweets that were posted before date X", I suggest to use database where you store this information.
Its worth taking a look at [hibernate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/), which offers an easy and structured way to talk to a database. If the amount of tweets is huge (in the millions), you will need to look for a scalable database (however most big databases offer this functionality nowadays).

If you don't need to process query's on the processed tweets, you could also store them into an XML/JSON file, which might be easier.

Comment: I looked at the link you gave about hibernate but i didn't imagine anything how to create database, because i never used some kind of database in Java before. Could you be more specific or at least give me an example related to my program?

Comment: Well in the past I've used a postgresql database (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_java.htm shows how you can use java to connect to it). However this requires you to write SQL code that creates the table/inserts/remove/manipulates it. Hibernate gives you the advantage that you actually don't need any knowledge of SQL. You access it as java objects. Giving an example is gonna be a bit lengthy, however I suggest you to try a basic example: replicate http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm it will help you to understand it on how to map it to your case.